# TM1 - passing data between cubes by linking a measure in the target cube to a dimension in the source cube

Tags: cognos-tm1

TM1 - linking measures to dimensions

I have two cubes in TM1, and I am trying to source data from one cube by linking a calculated 'Age' field in the target cube to an 'Age' dimension in the source cube. However, while I can do this fine by writing code in the rules editor, I cannot work out how to do it using the rules Wizard. Unfortunately, policy in my company is that all TM1 models must be based around wizard-based rules, so I am hoping someone could explain how to do this via the wizard.

Cube 1 (the source) contains data on how quickly a loan balance reduces due to customer attrition, based on the loan's age in months - it looks a bit like this: 

   `Age  |  Attrition % 
-------|--------------
   1   |   5% 
   2   |   6%
   3   |   7%` 

Cube 2 (the target) contains a loan balance, and calculates how the balance reduces over several months, based on the data in Cube 1. It looks up the data in cube 1, based on the age that is calculated in the first row of Cube 2, on the basis of:
  current month - start month + 1.
So if we assume the loan started in July, for August the age would be:
  8 - 7 + 1 = 2 months old.
For the loan starting in July, Cube 2 would look a bit like this:


                `| Jul | Aug | Sep |
----------------|-------------------
Age             |  1  |  2  |  3  |
Opening Balance | $100| $95 | $89 |
Attrition %     |  5% | 6%  | 7%  | <-- sourced from Cube 1 on basis of Age
Attrition $     | -$5 |-$5.7|-$6.3|
Closing Balance |  $95| $89 | $83 |`

Creating this link is trivial in Excel, but whenever I try to do it using the TM1 Rules Wizard, I run into the problem that TM1 does not seem to allow the linking of a dimension ('Age' in cube 1) to a field within a dimension ('Age' in cube 2).
Can anyone advise?